# ¿Tabla relacional en un Gridview?

Tags: asp.net

¿Es posible?.

Acabo de hacer un codigo simple en donde se hace una consulta a una tabla llamada "**infouser**" para mostrarlos en un Gridview.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, hay otra tabla aparte llamada **Roles** con estos atributos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que puedo hacer para que la columna Rol de **infouser**, se muestre como la columna Nombre de la tabla **Roles** si su ID coinciden?

Para lograr algo asi;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realmente no se como se le llame a este metodo, por lo que no se como deberia de buscarlo para investigar o resolverlo!

El código que he llevado hasta ahora funciona asi:

CÓDIGO FUENTE (el procedimiento almacenado seria un simple select * from infouser)

```
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("UserViewAll", sqlCon);
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
            sqlCon.Close();
            gvContact.DataSource = dtbl;
            gvContact.DataBind();
```

CODIGO HTML DEL GTRIDVIEW

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvContact" runat="server"  EmptyDataText="No han encontrado registros que mostrar"  AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Apellido" HeaderText="Apellido" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IdRole" HeaderText="Rol" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdUser") %>' OnClick="lnk_OnClick">Editar</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Lo más óptimo es que modifiques la consulta que te trae los datos de los usuarios para que te provea los valores con las tablas ya cruzadas así solo tienes que pintar en .Net los valores directamente.

Comment: Tu query tiene que unir las dos tablas. Investiga sobre joins ( o subconsultas)

Comment: ¿El inner Join no solo muestra 2 tablas juntas en un Gridview?, bueno, iré a ver si con ese método se puede hacer lo de mi pregunta...

Comment: Si pusieras el código con el que has intentado sería más fácil orientarte en qué parte te hace falta solucionar detalles

Comment: Gracias por tus consejos, acabo de ponerlo!

Comment: Tenes que modificar tu StoreProcedure para que devuelva lo que vos queres

Comment: Hasta ahora respondo, Muchas gracias me fueron utilices sus consejos, no tenia idea de los Join.